# Suggestion for choosing (building) loss funciton

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-function

I would like to build a supervised learning model M satisfying the following conditions:

1. Training data `{X, Y}`, where $x \in R^m$  and $y \in R^n$
2. Assume: `M(x) = p`, then: `0 < p[k] <= y[k]`, for all `k = 1:n`. Here I mean p[k] as close as possible to y[k]

Could you please suggest what are the "best" loss function and optimization method that I can use to train this model M?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give us more information. By the equation `0 < p[k] <= y[k]` I assume that `y` is a contiguous variable. Am I wrong?. What do you mean by `size(x)` and `size(y)`?  If they are vectors, are they `m` and  `n` dimensional vectors resp.? I guess you mean that you have `n` samples each represented by `m` dimensional vector.  The predicted value should be less than `y`, but If `y == 10`, what would be better:`p == 0` or `p == 10`??

Comment: Your question is very related to math and convex optimisation. I guess you won't be able to find invaluable answers here because in our community we even don't have that tag which considers the math perspective. Your question may suit to math community. You can ask there for introducing a way to make a convex cost function in order to find its optimal point.